# Multi-column listbox type control in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox, multiple-columns

Does there exists a listbox control in ASP.NET which allows multiple columns and multiple selection?

I looked but couldn't find, so what options do I have available now?

Answer (score 1):

Not natively, you might need a third party library or create your own. I have used DevExpress for this purpose before.

Comment: You could use a GridView, would this not work for your purpose?

Comment: I would have to add checkboxes for selection then, which is what I wanted to avoid. I would resort to it @ last, if no free solutions were available.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you won't be able to do it with normal asp .net ListBox control. [Telerik Listbox](http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax/listbox.aspx) supports list item templating, which allows you to have even a whole table of data within a list box item.

Answer (score 0):

this is possible all you have to do is to set it grammatically read this
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.multicolumn(v=vs.110).aspx